# How can I see/track users who have seem +3 pages on my google analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, dashboard, looker-studio

One of the company's KPIs is: "have seen +3 pages on the website".

On google analytics, I can see the pages/session metrics. I have tried to create the following segment but it didn't work (see screenshot). I still see pages/session under 3 and the numbers look a bit too low (second screenshot)

[segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmtvK.png)

[pages/session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjYRx.png)

I not only want to find out how I can see this info in analytics but and most importantly, I want to do 2 things:

1. Use this information to retarget these users with Facebook Ads
2. Display this information on a Google Data Studio Dashboard.

Any help with this would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: You've set session duration in the segment to = 1 second as well as segmented by "users", remove that and modify everything to sessions (per session), it should only show you sessions where pages/session is greater than 3

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **include** `sessions` instead of *users*, then remove the rules where *session duration is equals 1* (it doesn't make sense), so set `pageviews >= 3`:

[image]

In the report the value of `Pages / session` becomes representative:

[image]